# How can I asynchronously fetch data through the request library without waiting?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests

I want to fetch data from a website through the request library which takes around 1 second. I want a way not to wait there for the response instead doing rest work. How can I do that?

```
import requests

ra = requests.get('https://steemmonsters.com/settings').json()['sbd_price']

s = 1+1
n = 2+2
n = 22+3/3
bb = n + s*3
b = ra + 3

print(ra)
print(b)
```

Comment: https://github.com/ross/requests-futures